# What is Community Wiki for and how does reputation work on Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-wiki

This question may have been addressed in another post but I could not quite find what I was looking for.

My question is what exactly is Community Wiki and how does reputation work on Community Wiki?

I am curious because I answered a question last night that was originally posted on MSE. Then when I looked this morning the post had been moved to Community Wiki. I received a nice answer badge but obtained no reputation. Do you not receive reputation for Community Wiki answers?

Again sorry if this question has already been asked. I appreciate and comments. Thank you!

Comment: You can have a look at the older questions tagged [meta-tag:community-wiki] (or perhaps [community-wiki+reputation](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-wiki+reputation). And also the links given in the [tag-wiki](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info) might be useful. Short answer to one of your questions is that you [do not get reputation](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1603/8297) for votes on a CW-posts.

Answer (score 4):

You do not earn or lose reputation on Community Wiki (CW) posts. However, if some votes were cast before the post became a CW, you keep the points. This may be relevant for your answer to [another soft question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/555895/)   which I expect to become CW in near future.

For details of the CW feature, see [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740)