# What do score and answers tab represent?

Tags: support, badge-tracking, score

Below my reputation graph of SE Math there are tabs in green "score" , "answers".

What do they represent? (bit dumb asking it, shall delete this later). Thanks.

May be place the bars down?

[image]

Comment: Don't delete this question, it will help others find when they search it in the meta. The fact that such a simple question is not a duplicate indicates that its continued existence is beneficial.

Comment: Thanks, shall retain it.

Comment: I was just scratching my head over the same question earlier this week. Thanks for asking it.

Comment: You still need three upvotes in order to get the badge for ordinary differntial zquations questions.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean the part marked bellow:

[image: Screenshot]

It is right next to the [ordinary-differential-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordinary-differential-equations) tag selected in the "next tag badge". (Part of the [badge tracking](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/badge-tracking/info).)

It says 97/100 score, 164/20 answers.

To get a [bronze tag badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze), you need to have (in that particular tag) at least 20 non-CW answers and the total score at least 100. So this shows how far you're in these criteria. (You have score 97 - so you need three more upvotes to get the bronze badge. You already have more than 20 non-CW answers in that tag.)

Comment: OK, thanks for clarification.  It is placed at the side as linked.

Comment: Just to be clear: "non-CW" means [non-Community Wiki](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-is-community-wiki-for-and-how-does-reputation-work-on-community-wiki?r=SearchResults&s=1|100.6001) answers.